# How to install a setup in silent mode?

Tags: inno-setup

I have written the code to create an exe file using ISS(inno script). I need to run this created exe in silent mode.

Could anyone direct me to how to run this exe in silent way? Should i need to include any code in iss file?

Note: i have tried to run the created exe by running the console application in silent way which internally run the application created using iss.  But UI is displayed.

Could anyone help me and provide me the details that whether this is feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run your setup in silent mode you need to execute it with `/SILENT` command line parameter. This is described in the [`Setup Command Line Parameters`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline) topic as:

> **/SILENT, /VERYSILENT**
>
> Instructs Setup to be silent or very silent. When Setup is silent the
>   wizard and the background window are not displayed but the
>   installation progress window is. When a setup is very silent this
>   installation progress window is not displayed. Everything else is
>   normal so for example error messages during installation are displayed
>   and the startup prompt is (if you haven't disabled it with
>   DisableStartupPrompt or the '/SP-' command line option explained
>   above).
>
> If a restart is necessary and the '/NORESTART' command isn't used (see
>   below) and Setup is silent, it will display a Reboot now? message box.
>   If it's very silent it will reboot without asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute your APP in command line：

```
application.exe /verysilent # Don't show any UI
application.exe /silent #Show  UI
```

Comment: Is there any way to hide the message box during silent(very silent) installation of our application. Could you please help me?

Comment: When a setup is very silent this installation progress window is not displayed. you can execute your APP in command line：application.exe /verysilent.  Everything else is normal so for example error messages during installation are displayed and the startup prompt is (if you haven't disabled it with DisableStartupPrompt or the '/SP-' command line option explained above).